# Is It possible to bypass DEP if one of the linked dll or the exe itself is DEP disabled?

Tags: exploit, dep

i have a program named `x`. The program `x` have one modules which is `dep` disabled and all other modules linked with dep enabled.

What will be the state of the program `x` , when developing an exploit , do i need to bypass dep or is there any other way around as one module is dep disabled.

Or is there any advantage if one of the module of a program is dep disabled!!

Answer (score 1):

DEP (NX) is a per-process setting. If the EXE opts in, or if the default is to use DEP and it doesn't explicitly opt out, then the process will be protected regardless of any DLLs or other library modules.

Note that this is different from ASLR, which is a per-module setting. So even if you can't evade DEP directly, you can use return-oriented programming / return-to-libc with gadgets from any non-ASLR modules to gain arbitrary code execution anyhow (assuming, of course, you have the necessary memory corruption vulnerabilities).